# What kind of neural network can I use for time series classification (preferably in MATLAB)?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, neural-networks

I am pretty new to neural networks and am trying to figure out what network to use for my particular kind of data. I have a time series (frequency vs time) of radar returns. The radar either picks up a return from objectA, objectB, or no object. I would like to train a network to be able to determine what is in the radar sequence. I have 100 samples of each (objectA, objectB, no object). What network would be best for this? I am most comfortable with MATLAB.

Comment: A recurrent network. Particularly LSTM's and GRU's